# What is the Drive API change on September 13, 2021 about, and what should I respond to?

Tags: google-drive-api

Last month I got an email from The Google Drive Team.
It's about the Drive API change on September 13, 2021, and I have a question about it.

No matter how much I read, I don't understand what this update is about. Can someone explain in detail?

The Drive API I use now is set to use the save/load function among the settings for Play Game Service in the Google Play Console.

Do I have to respond to this update?

Below is the content of the email received:

> Please update your code as detailed below before September 13, 2021, to avoid failing requests.
>
> What do I need to know?
> Items that have a Drive API permission with type=domain or type=anyone, where withLink=true (v2) or allowFileDiscovery=false (v3), will be affected by this security update.
>
> In addition to the item ID, your application may now also need a resource key to access these items. Without a resource key, requests for these items may result in a 404 Not Found error (See below for details). Note that access to items that are directly shared with the user or group are not affected.
>
> Will this change affect me?
> If your application uses the Drive API to access files which have been shared with a user through link sharing, your application may be affected by this change.
>
> What do I need to do?
> To avoid errors accessing files, you must update your code for accessing files to include the appropriate resource keys. Details on how to do this for each of the affected Drive APIs is included below:
>
> Changes to the Drive API
> The resource key of an item is returned on the resourceKey field of the file metadata in the Drive API response.
>
> If the file is a shortcut file, then the resource key for the target of the shortcut can be read from the shortcutDetails.targetResourceKey field of the same resource.
> URL type fields such as exportLinks, webContentLink, and webViewLink will include the resourceKey.
> Requests to the Drive API can specify one or more resource keys with the X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys HTTP request header.
> Learn more about this change from the Drive API guide.
>
> Changes to Apps Script
> The DriveApp from Apps Script has been updated to return the resource key of a file or folder with the getResourceKey method.
>
> Note: When fetching a file or folder, the resource key can be specified on the getFileByIdAndResourceKey or getFolderByIdAndResourceKey methods.
> Changes to Drive UI Integrations
> If your application is integrated with the Drive UI to create or open items, it will receive resource keys when your application is invoked from the Drive UI.
>
> The state information for a New URL will contain folderResourceKey, which is the resource key of the folder where the new item should be created.
> The state for an Open URL will contain a mapping of file ID to resource key in the resourceKeys field.
> Learn more about integrating with the Drive UI on our website.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this email was worded very badly as it sounds like Google is telling you that if you don't change your code, things will break. The fact of the matter is Google doesn't know that, only you do.

**What is the update**

> Google Drive is releasing a security update that will apply to some Drive files. The security update will make Google Drive files more secure by updating their links to include a resource key and may lead to some new file access requests.

**Find your impacted files**

- On your computer, go to drive.google.com.
- At the top, type: is:security_update_applied or is:security_update_removed in the search bar.

**How you may be impacted**

> Once the security update is applied to a file, a resource key included in the URL will be required to access the file. Users who previously accessed or viewed the file won’t need the resource key in the URL. Only people who haven’t previously accessed the file will need the resource key to gain access. If they don’t have the URL with the resource key, they’ll need to request access to the file.

So if you share the file with someone New then they need to resource key, users who had been grated access previously should be fine.

**Will I know if someone can’t access a file I own because they don’t have a link with the resource key?**

> If someone requests access to one of your files with the security update, you’ll receive an email telling you whether they tried to access your file using an old link. You can then send the person a new link with the resource key so that they can gain access.

So if you do nothing and leave your application as is then, when you try to share a file with someone, you will get an email telling you that there is a problem.

[Security update for Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10729743)